# How to connect to this database? I can't connect

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

[image: img 1]
It is the image from my phpmyadmin. I can't create databases in phpmyadmin, I have to create them through cPanel and then It appears in the phpmyadmin like this. But I can't connect them to my php application.

Whatever I Do, It's can't connect to sql server. But Works properly on localhost on my computer.

Heres the code,

```
<?php
// Connection
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", 'root', '');
$db = mysql_select_db("grplusbd_mychat", $conn);
$json = '';
if(isset($_GET['rq'])):
    switch($_GET['rq']):
        case 'new':
            $msg = $_POST['msg'];
            $myid = $_POST['mid'];
            $fid = $_POST['fid'];
            if(empty($msg)){
                //$json = array('status' => 0, 'msg'=> 'Enter your message!.');
            }else{
                $qur = mysql_query('insert into msg set `to`="'.$fid.'", `from`="'.$myid.'", `msg`="'.$msg.'", `status`="1"');
                if($qur){
                    $qurGet = mysql_query("select * from msg where id='".mysql_insert_id()."'");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qurGet)){
                        $json = array('status' => 1, 'msg' => $row['msg'], 'lid' => mysql_insert_id(), 'time' => $row['time']);
                    }
                }else{
                    $json = array('status' => 0, 'msg'=> 'Unable to process request.');
                }
            }
        break;
        case 'msg':
            $myid = $_POST['mid'];
            $fid = $_POST['fid'];
            $lid = $_POST['lid'];
            if(empty($myid)){

            }else{
                //print_r($_POST);
                $qur = mysql_query("select * from msg where `to`='$myid' && `from`='$fid' && `status`=1");
                if(mysql_num_rows($qur) > 0){
                    $json = array('status' => 1);
                }else{
                    $json = array('status' => 0);
                }
            }
        break;
        case 'NewMsg':
            $myid = $_POST['mid'];
            $fid = $_POST['fid'];

            $qur = mysql_query("select * from msg where `to`='$myid' && `from`='$fid' && `status`=1 order by id desc limit 1");
            while($rw = mysql_fetch_array($qur)){
                $json = array('status' => 1, 'msg' => '<div>'.$rw['msg'].'</div>', 'lid' => $rw['id'], 'time'=> $rw['time']);
            }
            // update status
            $up = mysql_query("UPDATE `msg` SET  `status` = '0' WHERE `to`='$myid' && `from`='$fid'");
        break;
    endswitch;
endif;

@mysql_close($conn);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: db name : grplusbd_mychat is enough

Comment: I believe your db should be called by using "grplusdb_mychat". In the image you see an UI representation used by phpmyadmin to present you the db list in a friendlier way

Comment: What ever I know, In cpanel you can't create a user with the name `root`.  And password should not be blank. You are missing these things. Check your cpanel.

Comment: The above two comments are you main issues. You are also using depreciated mysql functions and are wide open to sql injection attacks

Comment: Have a look at the many, MANY questions about connecting to mysql at localhost (hint: try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost - as far as mysql is concerned they are NOT the same)

Comment: @symcbean OP states it works properly on localhost.

Comment: @Martin: all IP networked computers are "localhost".

Comment: Please read before use any software. https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/MySQL+Databases https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cpanel-databases/

Comment: @abkrim but if everyone read the manual then StackOverflow would die! (or at least, it would only be for complex issues solved by knowledgable professionals). That could be terrible! `:-D`

Comment: If all read at least once using the software manual not only StackOverflow would not die but would win in quality. One thing is ask and another to ask to do the work. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user in cpanel and assign db to this user, or if you have already created user, assign the db to that user

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ***MySQL® Databases*** link in CPanel to create a MySQL User who can then be called via the PHP script. In the same way CPanel generates MySQL tables, the CPanel interface also generates MySQL user accounts.

You may need to also in the same account creating page associate the new account with one or more databases. Then:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", 'grplusbd_usernm', 'password');
```

Usernames are - like database names - prepended with the account reference, in this case `grlusbd`.

CPanel will not let a root MySQL user access a database via a third party script. root is reserved specifically for CPanel (and server command line, I imagine).

Ps. `mysql_select_db("grplusbd_mychat", $conn);` is the correct way to reference a database name in the instance in your question. No need to piss about with `grplusbd/`.

## NOTE:

You should no longer be using *MySQL_* functions in PHP and should be using `MySQLi_` or `PDO` database interacton functions. *MySQL_* is now **DEPRECATED** and removed as of PHP7.

Stop using it, as soon as practically possible, and instead use **MySQLi** or **PDO**.

---

My reference: CPanel Version 56.0